# vim - python-mode - is there a way to send a Ctrl+C to a running script in pymode?

Tags: vim, python-mode

Is there a way to kill a python script that is being [run by Python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode#run-python-code)?  If the script were being run from the shell, you could press Ctrl+C to cause a KeyboardInterrupt, but this does not seem to work.  The only way that I have been able to kill it is to kill the vim process entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the problems recently [discussed in vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/vim_dev/interrupt/vim_dev/irITPpKnTP8/jM0541w9pSkJ) and in some other topics. This behavior requires patching vim source to have eventloop in a separate thread, but there is no patch for this yet.

Currently there is no way to do this. *Some* running python scripts may be interrupted by sending a `SIGINT`, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use :!python % to run the file, after putting in a breakpoint or otherwise.

Then you would be able to kill the python processs with Cntrl+C